# Android Vine App "Sign In with Twitter"

Tags: android, twitter, vine

I've just downloaded the Vine app for Android and I noticed that the "sign in with Twitter" feature is integrated with the Android Twitter app.

I mean, If you already signed with the Twitter application, and go to Vine, you don't have to do the sign-in process and authorize the app, and you're automatically logged into the app. The same happens if you were logged with Vine previously, and then go to Twitter.

Being Vine a Twitter application, the tight integration between both apps seems pretty obvious, but I wanted to know if is there any way to do this from any other third party app.

It would be great to provide the users this feature, and save them the login step, if they have done it previously in the native Twitter application.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Well why you dont use the simple API of Facebook or Twitter to make the login. When you integrate FB or Twitter the made the login through they own apps, so if the user selects logme with facebook you can try to login and check if the login is successful or not and if is successful the user dosen't need to login again and you store the token.

Of course you'll use basic configuration and API like this:

ConfigurationBuilder cnf= new ConfigurationBuilder(); 
cnf.setDebugEnabled(true);

mTwitter =new TwitterFactory(cnf.build()).getInstance();;
mTwitter.setOAuthConsumer(Constant.CONSUMER_KEY, Constant.CONSUMER_SECRET);